# create type of vector, but using two lists instead

Tags: r

Difficult for me to explain, so probably best to explain the result I'd like arrive at.
I want to get this result, a type of vector

```
var_labels = c(varA="Heavy", v1="Medium", varZ="Light", v99="None"  )

> var_labels
    varA       v1     varZ      v99 
 "Heavy" "Medium"  "Light"   "None"
```

but I want to create it from two lists

```
variable <- c( "varA", "v1", "varZ", "v99" )
labels <- c( "Heavy", "Medium", "Light", "None" )
```

It need it in identical format so I can use the vector within another piece of code.  For some context. The var_labels vector, will allow me to label the respective variables, but I have lots of variables. So instead of writing "variable=label" multiple times I hope it can be done with combining two lists (the variable names and variable labels). Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [`setNames`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html)`(labels, variable)`

Comment: I think need to better understand different object formats. Thanks, this works perfectly.